# Add a file to all directories in one line

Tags: linux, shell

I need to add file.txt to all root directories and display path them.

I was tried to use

```
touch /home/folder1/file.txt & touch /home/folder2/file.txt etc.
```

but maybe someone can help me to make it simpler?

Answer (score 2):

If your shell supports it (and most shells do, e.g. Bash and Zsh), you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), e.g.:

```
touch /home/folder{1..10}/file.txt
```

Comment: Brace expansion should work but wildcards will only glob to those directories that already contain a `file.txt`, so it's no good for creating new files.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one -

```
touch /home/{folder1,folder2}/file.txt
```

This is known as expansion, another answer to a similar issue here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435621/bash-brace-expansion-after-a-path-slash

Ben Voigt's answer is essentially the same - breat me to it, though it also shows you how you can use a range of numbers...

My answer will do exatly what you asked, hoever if you wanted folders 1-10 then Ben's answer is better...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to do this regardless of the folder names. (I really hope that the folder names are not folder1, folder2, ...).

```sh
ls -d */ | xargs -I {} touch {}/text.txt
```

This will make a text.txt file in all the directories. The `ls -d */` is there so that only the directories are affected.